# Events showing on a calendar is radically different formats

Tags: views, feeds, datetime

With event nodes imported using the Feeds Importer. How might I get the Jan 1 event to appear *only* on January 1st?

[image]

These events shown below on Jan 1 and 4 are all day events. Their individual date formats are listed below. The dates entered in both seem to be the same, but the difference in the rendering is baffling.

[image]
[image]

Additional information: Based on a helpful comment below. Here is what the Inspector shows in Firefox.

*Jan 1 event, should not span two days*

[image]
([full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyD3y.png))

*Jan 4 event with proper rendering*

[image]
([full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPX4G.png))

Comment: Is the January 1st date actually showing for 2 different days or is the div just floating over the 2nd date? Check firebug to see if there's anything going on with your CSS first as the only reason the value would actually span 2 days is if you had a start and end date that covered both days.

Comment: The dead line is January 1st yes. It should not be spanning over into Jan 2. Thanks for the hint. I looked into the dom inspector. I'll add that graphic above.

Comment: Do you have a value in your "to date" for the January 1st date? It looks like views thinks its a multi day value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I half-way solved my the issue by changing a Multi-day event to a single column. I have some more reading and research to do on importing calendar events but for now, the rendering is correct.

[image]

This setting is found in the Views Format box by clicking `Settings` next to `Format: Calendar`.

[image]